# Does the [Authorize] attribute on a hub apply to the OnConnection() method?

Tags: methods, authorization, signalr, signalr-hub

Does the authorize attribute on a hub apply to the OnConnection() method?

I ask, because if I apply the `[Authorize]` attribute to my hub, non-authorized users can still call this method.

Am I supposed to perform manual authorization on this method?

Answer (score 0):

SignalR provides the Authorize attribute to specify which users or roles have access to a hub or method. This attribute is located in the "Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR" namespace. You apply the Authorize attribute to either a hub or particular methods in a hub. When you apply the Authorize attribute to a hub class, the specified authorization requirement is applied to all of the methods in the hub. Without the Authorize attribute, a connected client can access any public method on the hub.

If you have defined a role named "Admin" in your web application, you could specify that only users in that role can access a hub with the following code.

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")] 
public class AdminAuthHub : Hub 
{ 
}
```

Or, you can specify that a hub contains one method that is available to all users, and a second method that is only available to authenticated users, as shown below.

```
public class SampleHub : Hub 
{ 
    public void UnrestrictedSend(string message){ . . . } 

    [Authorize] 
    public void AuthenticatedSend(string message){ . . . } 
}
```

The following examples address different authorization scenarios:

```
 [Authorize] – only authenticated users
  
 [Authorize(Roles = "Admin,Manager")] – only authenticated users in the specified roles
    
 [Authorize(Users = "user1,user2")] – only authenticated users with the specified user names
    
 [Authorize(RequireOutgoing=false)] – only authenticated users can invoke the hub,
 but calls from the server back to clients are not limited by authorization, such as, when only 
 certain users can send a message but all others can receive the message. 
 The RequireOutgoing property can only be applied to the entire hub, not on individuals methods within the hub. When RequireOutgoing is not set to false, only users that meet the authorization requirement are called from the server.
```

You can get more details in this [article](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/security/hub-authorization)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, however with the `Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR` [Authorize] attribute the OnConnected() method is still called for unauthorized users.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I've just realised why the method was being called for non-authorized users.

It was because I had the following on my hub:

```
[Authorize(RequireOutgoing=false)]
```

And not just simply:

```
[Authorize]
```

The RequireOutgoing named parameter causes the `OnConnection()` method to be called for non-authorized users.

Comment: If you noticed my answer down the bottom,  I have mentioned the RequieOutgoing property and you need to set that to false so only authorised users access your hub.